# oracle sql - define date as variable in a with statement

Tags: sql, oracle

in oracle - i am trying to figure out how to define variables in a with statement.

when i define a variable as a number it works fine:

```
with a as(
    select 100 as query_rows
    from dual
)

,b as (
    select * from table1 where rownum=query_rows
)

select * from b --working great
```

however,if i want to define a date as a variable,i keep getting an error:

```
with a as(
    select DATE '2020-10-01' as query_date
    from dual
)

,b as (
    select * from table1 where table1.date=query_date
)

select * from b --  ORA-00904 : "query_date" is not a valid identifier
```

from oracle :ORA-00904

> You tried to execute a SQL statement that included an invalid column name or the column name is missing. This commonly occurs when you reference an invalid alias in a SELECT statement.

so,why does the first query work and the second one doesn't?

Comment: Are you sure the first query "works great"? I don't believe that. It will fail for the exact same reason as the second query - this has nothing to do with the data type. In your first query, you are using the column name without referencing the subquery `a` from the `with` clause - just the same as in your second example. Oracle won't know what that identifier means - it's not about data types. So: did that first query **really** work for you, **exactly as written**? Really?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CTE table in query as follows:

```
with a as(
    select DATE '2020-10-01' as query_date
    from dual
)
,b as (
    select * from table1 cross join a where table1.date=a.query_date
)
Select * from b;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you need to refer to cte you are using(here using subquery):

```
with a as(
    select DATE '2020-10-01' as query_date
    from dual
) ,b as (
    select * 
    from table1 
    where table1.date = (SELECT query_date FROM a) -- IN if more than one row is allowed
) 
select * from b
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Tejash, you don't need to use `b`:

```
with a as(
    select DATE '2020-10-01' as query_date
    from dual
)
select * from table1 cross join a where table1.date=a.query_date
```

Comment: Obviously, it is not needed. But I followed OP's query. But yeah, thanks for adding it here.